# Which group is meant by $\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

There is a question in my [question paper](http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2014/Files/GS2012_QP_MTH.pdf) (Q. No. 11 - Part B) which tells to verify whether

> The automorphism group $\text{Aut} (\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2)$ is abelian.

I don't understand which group is meant here by $\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2?$ Is it $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2?$

Comment: Yes, it is the same group. The $\times$ means that you take the product set with componentwise operations, and the product and direct sum of two abelian groups are the same.

Comment: @PabloZadunaisky: What about the symbol "/"?

Comment: Some people use $\mathbb{Z}/2$ to be short for $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$, as you suspected.

Comment: The symbol $/2$ is just shorthand for $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. It's meant to denote that you're "modding out" by the even integers - i.e., setting every even integer to zero.

Comment: What do you mean the automorphism group is "abelian 12"? I ask because it is neither abelian nor of order $\;12\;$ ...

Comment: Someone should post an answer to this question, as it is already answered by your comments. :-)

Comment: @DanielRust: I think this comes from the ring context where ${\bf Z}/2$ is shorthand for ${\bf Z}/(2)$, which is simply the quotient by the ideal generated by $2$.

Comment: Hint: The group $\mathbb Z_2\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ has three non-zero elements, all of order two. And the sum of any two is the third. Therefore any permutation of those three elements is an automorphism.