# Let $G$ and $H$ be two abelian groups. Is it true that $\text{Aut}(G\times H)\cong\text{Aut}(G)\times\text{Aut}(H)$?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Let $G$ and $H$ be two abelian groups. Is it true that $\text{Aut}(G\times H)\cong\text{Aut}(G)\times\text{Aut}(H)$?

I am trying to figure out $\text{Aut}(G)$ where $G=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}\bigoplus \mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The answer is implied by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595598/edited-t-f-the-automorphism-group-textaut-mathbb-z-2-times-mathbb-z?rq=1

Comment: The "natural strategy" is to start with $G = H$ (since that affords the possibility of "swapping the factors"), and then to take $G$ the simplest non-trivial group, i.e., the cyclic group of order $2$. Aha...this resolves the question (as Dietrich's answer shows). <> As a general matter, when seeking counterexamples, always try to choose them as simply as possible.

Comment: For your example, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27200/number-of-automorphisms-of-a-direct-product-of-two-cyclic-p-groups) with $p=5$ and $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, we have $\rm{Aut}(C_2\times C_2)\cong S_3$, see [Show $\operatorname{Aut}(C_2 \times C_2)$ is isomorphic to $D_6$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130221/show-operatornameautc-2-times-c-2-is-isomorphic-to-d-69), but ${\rm Aut}(C_2)$ is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

If the groups are finite then it is true if $\gcd(|G|,|H|)=1$.